# Como fazer o texto de uma celula ocupar duas linhas dentro da mesma celula no Crystal Reports com C# winForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

Estou criando um relatório com Crystal Reports. Ele está a funcionar, mas tem o seguinte problema:

Quando o conteúdo da celula é maior que o seu espaço, uma parte do conteúdo não aparece. Como faço para passar para baixo a parte que não aparece?

Comment: Só marcar a célula como **`CanGrow`**

Comment: Muito obrigado @jbueno!

Answer (score 4):

Marque a célula como **`CanGrow`** (ou **`PodeCrescer`**, se estiver em português) clicando com o botão direito do mouse em cima da célula.